# Variables undefined in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm been having some trouble playing around with the backbone.js library recently - namely the variables that I instantiate (both an extended View and Model) remain undefined.

Here's some code to show you what I mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var img = new ImageUrl();
var search = new ImageSearchDialogue({el: '.imageUrl', model: img}).render();


});
</script>
```

Here's the script that I've placed in the HTML document - both variables are undefined however. (I've checked with Firebug)

Is this a scoping issue perhaps?

Comment: So I'm assuming that `ImageUrl` extends a `Backbone.Model` and the `ImageSearchDialogue` extends a `Backbone.View`? Also the Backbone and Jquery libraries have been included in the page?

Comment: Yep to the first question. The libraries have been included in this order: jquery, underscore, backbone.

Comment: I checked them out in a console window after running the code through a browser. (both firefox & chrome) - The variables 'img' and 'search' are both undefined. 
I'm able however to create new instances from both relevant Constructor functions in said console window.

Comment: This image may clears things up in my above comment:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v282/Ace_of_Spades01/console.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it that you’re expecting the variables to be defined globally? They’re currently only defined in the scope of the function. Try this:

```
window.img = new ImageUrl();
window.search = new ImageSearchDialogue({el: '.imageUrl', model: img}).render();
```

Comment: Hmm this could be the case. But I've noticed that there's another View object that I can instantiate that is visible in the global scope.
     var menu = new Menu({el: '#menu'});

This one however is not passed a model object argument.

Comment: As an aside, you can make variables global when defining in the scope of a function by not including a 'var'. 

e.g. img = new ImageUrl();